# Pypi / pip blocks while downloading grpcio-reflection

Tags: python, pip, grpc, pypi

Installing `grpcio-reflection` with pip takes a really long time.

It is strange because the pip package is only 8KB in PyPI but downloading takes more than a minute while other packages that are in the megabytes are downloaded really fast.

UPDATE:
It was not downloading, there is a lot of compilation going on. It seems to be that the feature is still in alpha so the package is not precompiled like standard grpcio

UPDATE2: Repro steps

I have just opened an issue here: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/12992 and I am copying the repro steps here for completion.

It seems that grpci-reflection package installation freezes depending on other packages in the same command line

This can be easily reproduced by these two docker different containers:

Dockerfile.fast  - Container creation time ~1m 23s

```
#Download base ubuntu image
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install ca-certificates curl

# Prepare pip 
RUN apt-get -y install python-pip
RUN pip install -U pip
RUN pip install grpcio grpcio-tools
RUN pip install grpcio-reflection         # Two lines is FAST
```

Dockerfile.slow  - Container creation time 5m 20s

```
#Download base ubuntu image
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install ca-certificates curl

# Prepare pip
RUN apt-get -y install python-pip
RUN pip install -U pip
RUN pip install grpcio grpcio-tools grpcio-reflection  # Single line is SLOW
```

Timing containers build time:

```
time docker build --rm --no-cache -f Dockerfile.fast -t repro_reflbug_fast:latest .
......
real    1m22.295s
user    0m0.060s
sys     0m0.040s

time docker build --rm --no-cache -f Dockerfile.slow -t repro_reflbug_slow:latest .
.....
real    6m28.290s
user    0m0.052s
sys     0m0.052s
.....
```

I didn't have time yet to investigate but the second case blocks for a long time while the first one doesnt.

Comment: Download seems to be fast but after that installation seems to be slowed down almost to a halt. I didn't looked why (yet). Perhaps problems with some dependencies — the package lists `cython` and `protobuf` as dependencies.

Comment: On what platform are you working? With what version of `pip`? Are you working with a virtual environment (doing so is recommended) and if so with what version of `virtualenv`?

`grpcio-reflection` is pure Python so (provided you have `grpcio` and `protobuf` installed separately) there shouldn't be any compilation going on when you install it.

Comment: @NathanielManistaAtGoogle Hi Nathaniel, thanks for your interest. I have updated the question, added repro steps and also created a ticket in github. Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Thanks; let's continue investigation in [issue 12992](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/12992).

Comment: @NathanielManistaAtGoogle sorry to use this channel to ask, but does this issue makes sense or it is just that I am doing something wrong? https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/13010

Comment: @purpletentacle: I have routed [issue 13010](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/13010) to a better assignee for myself; follow along there for help with what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this issue was accepted as valid in the corresponding GitHub repo. It is now being discussed here:

https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/12992